# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: other assets on Amazon S3 demanding to be precompiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

So we've got our Rails 3.1(.1) site with assets in a few different places, and *Rails (for some reason) expects those images hosted on Amazon S3 to be precompiled*. The site-specific ones (stylesheets, little layout images, etc.) are local, they get successfully precompiled in production, and stored in `public/assets`, just like they should. They're served up via Apache **just fine**.

We have images that have URLs stored in the database that point at CDN-hosted images, and these URLs don't have a file extension; instead they have an MD5. They're `http://path-to-cdn.com/<BIG-'OLE-MD5-HASH>`. They're served through our views using Rails' `image_tag` helper **just fine**, they show up in production, they don't get sucked into our pre-compilation business (because they're dynamic, really, based on the product page on our site).

What's not fine are a third set of assets; they're stored on Amazon S3 with a *similar* hostname to where our site is served in production (the site is at, say, `store.hostname.com` and the assets are sitting at `images.hostname.com.s3.amazonaws.com`). When we visit a page with one of those images (and these images *do* have some sort of an extension; `.jpg | .png | .gif`, etc), we get a `500` error and a Sprockets error is filed about that image's URL not being precompiled.

I've seen some solutions where people feed a `Proc` to `config.action_controller.asset_host`, but I'm not sure that applies to my situation. I can't seem to find an answer to my solution.

Is there any way — besides writing the URL on the page to a raw HTML image tag (`<img src=""/>`) instead of a Rails `image_tag`? We'd really like to be able to use those nice helpers.

Comment: How are you generating the urls for the images on s3?

Comment: They're literally files that have been uploaded there from another application that uses the same database tables as this one. They're stored in the DB as `http://images.hostname.com.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/image-01.png`. That's then fed into an image_tag, like in ERB: `<%= image_tag(@product.image_url) %>`

Comment: So `image_url` is a column in your `products` table and it has values like `http://images.hostname.com.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/image-01.png`? `image_tag` should only be looking for an asset if you supply it a path. I'm not sure why it's looking for an asset if you're supplying a full url.

Comment: Yep — I was digging through `rails/rails` this morning on Github and you're right. It shouldn't be looking for an asset [if the path is/resembles a URI](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/asset_paths.rb#L26). A straight HTML tag works: `<img src="<%= @product.image_url %>" />` Not sure why.

Comment: @James: thanks a million for your comment. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark you credit for it. The URI that was being fed to `image_tag` had trailing whitespace in front of it somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from the comments it looks like the image urls in your database had whitespace as the first character which caused `image_tag` to look for an asset instead of linking straight to the url.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this. I don't think I ever would've noticed this if I hadn't seen your answer.